# As a Non-US freelancer, do I need to pay tax in the USA for money earned outside USA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen, will go to USA for my PhD few days later on a student VISA (F1).

I have <1000 USD in my account of a freelancing site that I plan on withdrawing after going to USA. The money was of course earned here in Bangladesh. Do I need to pay any tax on this?

Please note: Bangladesh has 0% tax rate for freelancing work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, USA IRS is interested in earnings, not assets.

Earnings are taxed when you earn it.  You were not associated in any way with the USA then, so you don't need to report the *income*.

However, USA Immigration is interested in assets.  First they want to know you have enough money to accomplish your travel goals consistent with your visa, without "going on the dole" (using the social safety net of welfare, food stamps, public housing, health care such that it is, etc.)

US Customs is also interested in the amount of *cash* you are carrying.  They generally expect to see "pocket money" (e.g. enough for a cab ride from the airport and some restaurant meals) but dislike seeing thousands of dollars of cash, which is often an indicator of criminal activity.  Use the normal banking system to move money electronically.